# typescript asserts if returns not null (with typeguard)

Tags: typescript, assert, type-inference

I am trying to check some property of a variable with a regular Expression and if that matched, I want the type of that variable be inferred to a more specific type.

I have an example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAHgclAvFABjAJAbwHYFcC2ARhAE4C+KA3ALABQAxgPbYDOwUJEA5othAO5QAStwCiMMAAoARDEkBtAAwBaAJwBdANQBKadpq06AM1zZ6wAJbMo9ABYR6Aa0ksAXGxIXsXba5FdxMABZAENgOwBBEhIQkCgAHyg8ABtkqAB6ACooEJYWUmAWKCKLIvhM9Mw6KA4IYFwSbGKAOnwwu0lOHwMyOjoAEwdkkM4bZjYoYAgJ92BPbwMmVnY28NskG3snSSm2fT7aCyNJVbttKtoa9PTd9hZbRlxk-qhiKEYjSfBoeCTGfmqUFOtmaXBIjzARWuUFw+UmtjCf2wyhSaWBUAAbiMLCFCMkIAAaSaMRjNMl0MhAA):

```js
type xN = `x${number}`;
const reg = new RegExp("x([0-9]+)");

function check(s:string):RegExpMatchArray | null /* asserts s is xN*/{
  return s.match(reg);
}

declare const test :string;
const match = check(test);

if(match){
  // test should be of type xN now
  match.groups // use that non-null match variable, too...

}
```

Is there a way to do that with one function in (TS 4.5.4)? If not, how would you do it neatly?

Comment: Do you know that test is the exact value

Comment: @Xiao_e_yun I'm not sure I understand. That is what the type-guard should tell me after it returned. So `test` can be `x1`, ... or `y1`, ... The guard should then return the match or `null` respectively. If it returns `null`, `test` should still be just `string`, otherwise it can be inferred, that `test` is indeed of type `xN`

Comment: The missing feature you need is requested at [ms/TS#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650).  It's marked as "Awaiting More Feedback" so if you want to see it happen you might want to give it a  and describe why your use case is compelling

Comment: I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZrr1m) is the closest you can get right now if you must do two things in one function, but it's not the workflow you really want, which is currently not possible. Should I write up an answer mentioning this ans ms/TS#46650?  Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Base on Single responsibility principle, I don't think you should do both in a function. It makes your application more complicated.

Instead of that, you can break it into two functions like that:

```
type xN = `x${number}`;
const reg=new RegExp("x([0-9]+)");

function isXn(s: string): s is xN {
  return true
}

function check(s: xN):RegExpMatchArray {
  return s.match(reg)!; // !: since xN is always match reg
}

declare const test :string;

if(isXn(test)){
  //test is xN now
  const match = check(test);
  match.groups // use that non-null match variable, too...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the string is xN

```
type xN = `x${number}`;
const reg=new RegExp("x([0-9]+)");

function check(input:string): input is `${string}${xN}${string}` {
  return !!input.match(reg)
}

let checkStr:string
if (check(checkStr)) {
  checkStr
  // ^? `x${number}`(xN)
} else {
  checkStr
  // ^? string
}
```

If you know exactly the string (string is constant), it allows you to know the correct string.

```
function getValue<T extends string>(input:T){
  const reg=new RegExp("x([0-9]+)");
  const match = input.match(reg)
  if(match) return match[1] as T extends `x${infer W}` ? W : null
  else return null
}

const knowStr1 = "x356363"
const value1 = getValue(knowStr1)
//    ^? "356363"

const knowStr2 = "hi"
const value2 = getValue(knowStr2)
//    ^? null
```

Comment: Now I see what you mean, no the string is not constant. The guard should check and then depending on the return value (which is checked at runtime) and the control flow (`if(result)...`) determine the possible types. Like here  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40562#issuecomment-983050831

Comment: Does the first example function as you say

Comment: well, yes it gives the right type, but then, to get the value, I'd need to run the regexp again. (In my actual example it not as simple as a regex but involves more)